# Is a SP-GiST index faster with integers than it is with doubles?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 and have a table that contains `lat, lng` points, with each point having a column `lat` and a column `lng` as doubles. Right now, I have a `SP-GiST` index defined as

```
CREATE INDEX territories_box_gist_idx ON territories
USING gist (box(point(lat, lng), point(lat, lng)));
```

which works well, but I'm really pushing for performance, as I have around 200 million rows of these points.

The nice part about these points, and the premise of my question, is that they're all evenly spaced out, so I could actually create integer columns such as `row` and `col` that would allow me to get nearby points just as well. Would a SP-GiST index with these integers or any other index be faster than what I have currently?

Comment: Note: your index is actually GiST, not SP-GiST. You should create the index with `USING spgist` for SP-GiST (they are somewhat similar, but actually two entirely different index methods).

Answer (score 0):

If you need geometric data types, you are stuck with floating point numbers, since they are all based on those.

Also, the price you might potentially pay for floating point operations is probably small, since you don't need so many of them during index access and modification.